# Foundation nav classes are not visible as navigation bar

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Here is my HTML code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>{+title /}</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <ul class="left">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a><li>
                            <li><a href="/pages/about">About</a><li>
                            <li><a href="/cart">Cart</a><li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                <nav>
            </div>
        </div>
            {+body /}



        <script data-main="/js/app" src="/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And My Out put is following - it seems that no CSS is affecting. Please note one thing that my foundation CSS is included and I have tested that.

[image]

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: @alldani yes but o/p coming s in screensshot

Comment: It wasn't a yes or no question, my question is *how* did you test that the CSS is connected?

Comment: @alldani Open source by ctrl+U then click the css URL it was opening with source code.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's properly linked. You need a visual change. What's the live link, if any?

Comment: @alldani https://jsfiddle.net/hat206gm/2/  Please access here

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing Foundation init call. Add this before the end of the BODY tag:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Here is a syntax for v6.3:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation Starter Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">One</a>
                    <ul class="menu vertical">
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
                <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.0/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not Working yet :(

Comment: are you still using v5?  v6.3 has a slightly different syntax, see http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/top-bar.html

Comment: Using 6.3 version

Comment: Your syntax is for v5.5, see the sample I added to my answer for v6 syntax

Comment: in googling you're getting the v5.5.3 docs. but if your files are v6.3 that's the answer for you: @AshutoshOjha